# ArrayList of Characters

Tags: java, arraylist, character

I want to create an ArrayList of character objects based off the characters in a string of letters.  But, I can't seem to figure out how to fill that ArrayList to match the String.  I've been trying to have it iterate through the string so that later, if I change the content of the string it'll adjust.  Regardless, no matter what I do I'm getting some sort of syntax error.

Could anybody please guide me in the right direction?  Thanks a bunch!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.text.CharacterIterator;   //not sure if this is necessary??

public class Test{

//main method

     String words = new String("HELLO GOODBYE!");
     ArrayList<Character> sample = new ArrayList<Character>();

     for(int i = 0; i<words.length(); i++){
         sample.add((char)Character.codePointAt(sample,i));
     }
}
```

Comment: char[] charArray = words.toCharArray();

Comment: In your case `sample.add(words.charAt(i));` should work

Comment: would this still add them as character objects??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your case, `words.charAt()` is enough.

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;

  public class Test{

       String words = new String("HELLO GOODBYE!");
       ArrayList<Character> sample = new ArrayList<Character>();

       for(int i = 0; i<words.length(); i++){
           sample.add(words.charAt(i));
       }
  }
```

**Read more:** [Stirng](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/), [Autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Comment: Thank you! would this still be considered as adding character objects?

Answer (score 1):

This code adds all the characters in a character array to an `ArrayList`.

```
Character[] letters = {'a', 'b', 'c', ...};
List<Character> array = new ArrayList<Character>();
array.addAll(Arrays.asList(letters));
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.